# problem locating folder in ubuntu

Tags: nautilus, directory

I am new to ubuntu so sorry for stupid question.

I can go

```
cd /usr
```

in terminal and it lead me to /usr

but i dont see any folder named usr in computer

[image]

can anyone please help me understand what does this means !!

Comment: In your terminal window you are looking at /usr/*. In your file explorer window you are looking at /home/your_user_name/*.

Comment: It is probably under `+ Other Locations`  ??

Comment: @DougSmythies so how do i go there?

Comment: oh yes, thank you it was under + Other Locations !! I can't believe i did not see it !! Thank you so much

Comment: Why did you tag your question `14.04`? If this is the version you're using I'd recommend to install a recent version of Ubuntu asap. 14.04 is End of Life for several years now and therefor not supported anymore on AskUbuntu. I removed this tag from your question since it's not version specific.

Comment: sorry mine is 22.04

Answer (score 1):

In your screenshot, you are not looking at "Computer". You are looking at "Home". "Home" is your user home directory: `/home/.

You will find the system folders, including `usr`, under "Other Locations", "On this computer". You also can navigate to any folder by showing the location bar (hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) and typing the path, e.g. `/`  for the root directory. In that root directory, you will see `usr`.